# Is "Information Coefficient" correlation or rank correlation?

Tags: correlation, performance-evaluation

From the textbook, *information coefficient (IC)* is a measure of the depth of an active manager’s skill. On a more formal basis, IC measures the “correlation” between actual returns and those predicted by the portfolio manager (Grinold & Kahn, 2000; Fabozzi & Markowitz, 2011). Cross-checking [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/information-coefficient.asp) suggests the same thing. That is, it's the *pearson correlation* between returns and scores. However, my colleague is adamant that it's the *rank correlation* not the pearson correlation. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your purpose. Rank correlation as information coefficient makes sense for cross-sectional strategies.

Example: You are running a long-short fund. Start by ranking the returns of assets for the next time period then go long on high ranked assets and go short on low ranked assets.